# Google spreadsheet sumif adds, condition with string comparison

Tags: google-sheets

The task is to sum up the values of specific people. 
I have created the table, and found all the unique surnames. However, the formula's condition won't work.

Here is [>>the example<<](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11EgrlMIf1y21FdJ9rA-cMbBcA00w54j4NlT_bdP-9Y0/edit#gid=0):

Here is the formula

```
=sumif(A2:A25,"=H2",F2:F25)
```

The exact formula is in red

A2:A25 the surnames
"=H2"  unique surname
F2:F25 money

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put a cell reference in a string...

```
=sumif(A2:A25,"="&H2,F2:F25)
```

Here is another way to do it as a bonus:

```
=query(A:F,"select sum(F) where A is not null and A = '"&H2&"' GROUP BY A label sum(F) ''",-1)
```